# When can you have discontinuous solution to Schrodinger equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, quantum-mechanics

For a usual KE+PE Schrodinger equation (which is just a second order ODE), I know that you cannot have a physically preparable discontinuous wavefunction solution. However I am interested in mathematially valid solutions for $\psi$.

I have heard that we can only guarantee that $\psi$ must be continuous if the potential function $V(x)$ is continuous. Does this mean that in the case of a finite square well $V(x)$ with a discontinuity, there is a valid discontinuous solution for $\psi$ (mathematically at least)?

$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2} + V(x) \psi = E \psi$

Comment: This is a hard topic but it has a bit of discussion on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-the-wave-function-have-to-be-continuous).

Comment: @K.defaoite but ultimately are discontinuous mathematical solutions for $\psi$ possible?

Comment: From the second derivative of the jumps in $\psi$ you would get $\delta'$ terms on the left side, while the right remains a bounded piecewise continuous function. It would be hard to establish equality of both sides.

Comment: @Alex Gower **I don't know.** If I *did*, I would have commented about it, not directed you to a Quora page.

Answer (score 1):

It dependson what you mean by "solution".

Typically, one would define a solution as a function $\psi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $-\frac{\hbar}{2m}\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}(x)+V(x)\psi(x)=E\psi(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Clearly, for this to be the case, $\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}$ must be well defined, and so $\psi$ must be twice differentiable and thus continuous.

Often times, however, one is instead interested in [weak solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_solution) of the Schrödinger equation, which are solutions of a corresponding integral equation on some space of functions. Depending on the choice of weak formulation, weak solutions need not be functions at all (distributions or equivalence classes of functions are also common). Ultimately, whether discontinuous weak solutions exist (or if that statement even makes sense) depends on which weak formulation of the Schrödinger equation you're using.